# How to make a link work only if it is clicked from a particular website?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have two websites:

1. Website-1 which is built in ASP. The user has login ID and password.
2. Website-2 which I have built using PHP/MySQL. This is an unprotected website, having no login ID and password.

Now, I have given the link to Website-2 on the homepage of Website-1. Up on logging into Website-1, the user clicks the link to Website-2.

What I want is: if the user has actually clicked the link from Website-1, he can access Website-2.

In case the user tries to access Website-2 directly by using the URL, he should be directed to some neutral website such as Google.com. How do I program in PHP in Website-2 so as to block such users?

Pl. help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: about the only pratical option is to check referers, which is pretty much utterly unreliable.

Comment: There is no legitimate way to check from where the link was clicked.

Comment: Though not a sure shot solution but you  can try cookies.. when website 2 is loading check if a particular cookie is present with the browser and accordingly redirect...

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/827/how-to-set-up-a-single-sign-on-for-multiple-domains

Comment: [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) may also be related.

Comment: Create something to generate a token and tie it to the user_id on Web Site 1, navigate the user over to Web Site 2 with the token in the URL then   verify that the token exist in the DB on Web Site 2, if it does then allow the user in; if not; bye bye